# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `stage' for #<User:0x007f80045ca0e0>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an error with a form in a view, can't get it why is happening. I keep getting `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'stage' for #<User:0x007f80045ca0e0>)`

I have two models, User and Stage. User `has_many` stages, and stages `belongs_to` to user. It's as follows

The Stage Model:

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

The User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_one :user_setting       
    has_many :matches,      dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :stages,   dependent: :destroy 

end
```

and in the user controller I have as follows:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @newMatch = current_user.matches.new
        @newStage = current_user.drivepipes.new
    end

end
```

and a form on the show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [current_user], url: user_stages_path(current_user, @newStage) do |s| %>

    <%= s.text_field :stage,                placeholder: "Stage" %>

    <%= s.submit "Save" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: this should be `has_many :stages` instead of `stage`

Comment: You have `has_many :stage` instead of `has_many :stages` in the code.

Comment: typo, but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you tell me on which line did the error is raised?

Comment: Do you have `stage` attribute in your `users` table?

Comment: What do expect be the output of `s.text_field :stage`?

Comment: no, it's in the stage model/table

Comment: @Pavan it raises on the line that says `<%= s.text_field :stage,                placeholder: "Stage" %>`

Comment: @TiagoOrnelasVieira What exactly are you trying to do by keeping a text_field for `stage`? What do you think it should do?

Answer (score 0):

If each user has many stages and you're making a form for your user, `<%= s.text_field :stage, placeholder: "Stage" %>` is going to give you an error because the user `has_many :stages` which is an enumerable. So you're going to want something like

```
<%= form_for [current_user], url: user_stages_path(current_user, @newStage) do |s| %>
  <% current_user.stages.each do |stage| %>
    <%= s.text_field stage, placeholder: "Stage" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= s.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming you want a text field for every stage the user has, that is. Perhaps that's not the goal here?

Comment: why use the each method?

Comment: Since your relationship is one to many the method is :stages, not :stage. So you need to accept parameters for the Stage model.

You can also use the fields_for method in your form. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: @TiagoOrnelasVieira because it's an enumerable and you said it has a one-to-many relationship implying that each user has multiple stages, thus the `each` is required to show them all.

Answer (score 0):

There is one-to-many relationship between User and Stage. So, foreign key will reside in Stage table i.e. user_id. You should make clear that You can't have an attribute 'stage' or stage_id in User object if it has many stages. However Rails have helpers:

```
@user.stages
```

will return array of stages which have been saved with this user's id, using query:

```
select * from stages where stages.user_id = @user.id
```

While:

```
@user.stage
```

will raise error.

If you want to get input for newly created stage object associated with current user, You view code should look like this:

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: user_stages_path(current_user, @newStage) do |user_form| %>

    <%= user_form.fields_for @newStage do |stage| %>
      <%= stage.text_field :stage, placeholder: "Stage" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= user_form.submit "Save" %>

<% end %>
```

Later, in controller; you can get the stage object in the similar way:

```
stage = Stage.new params[:user][:stage]
```